# Paste from script into Chromium

Tags: command-line, xserver

I'm trying to write a script to convert a file and copy the converted text to the clipboard so I can paste it into a website. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3892/6709) got me started. My script contains, in part:

```
xsel -ib < txt/"$BASE".txt
```

After running that command, I can paste into my text editor (Geany) no problem. However, when I paste into Chromium, nothing gets pasted; Chromium seems to think the clipboard is empty. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses both the clipboard-proper and the primary clipboard, and in this instance is attempting to paste from the wrong clipboard. Try this instead:

```
xsel -ip < txt/"$BASE".txt
```

[There's a whole load of more detail in this post on Unix.SE.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190562/202555)

Comment: Unfortunately, using the primary clipboard as you suggest pastes nothing, in Chromium or in Geany. However, after trying my original script in Chromium again (with `xsel -ib`), it now works for reasons I don't understand.